# What is the most efficient way to get all documents from multiple sub-collections of multiple sub-collections in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I have a collection with a structure as such:

| Collection | Documents | Sub-Collection | Documents |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| users | user1 | invoices | inv1 |
|  |  |  | inv2 |
|  |  |  | inv3 |
|  | user2 | invoices | inv1 |
|  |  |  | inv2 |
|  |  |  | inv3 |
|  | user3 | invoices | inv1 |
|  |  |  | inv2 |
|  |  |  | inv3 |

Let's say I have over 200 users with each user having over 500 invoices.

I am using Firestore as a backend for my ReactJS app. So I currently have the ability to pull each user's invoices when I access their `userId`. However, I want to have a new feature on a new page where I can access ALL INVOICES at once. So what is the most efficient way for me to do this?

A couple of scenarios that I could think of:

1. Create a cloud function where it compiles all Invoices from each user into a single new user with the name `All Users`.
2. Iterate through all the `userId` to get all of the invoices from each user.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have a new feature on a new page where I can access ALL INVOICES at once. So what is the most efficient way for me to do this?

If you want to get all invoices of all users, then you should consider using a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Since you say that:

> Let's say I have over 200 users with each user having over 500 invoices.

Then we speak about 100k documents, which is way too much to get in a single go. For that, I recommend you get the data in smaller chunks by implementing [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).

Regarding the first scenario, it will work, but it doesn't make any sense to do that since we have collection group queries.

Regarding the second scenario, it will also work but you need to store somehow all user IDs and then perform a separate query for each user. It complicates things a bit.

Comment: Hey Owenn. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?